# Parsing of String in sql

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have data coming as

```
**Column**
A/B(D)C
```

Need output as

```
Column1  Column2  Column3 Column4    
   A          B           D        C
```

Tried to use String Split where i can split only one delimiter which is not as expected

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a few minutes and read through FAQ in order to learn how to properly submit a question. Images are not very helpful, especially in your case.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('A/B(D)C'),
('Miami/Orlando(Denver)Hollywood');
-- DDL and sample data population, start

SELECT t.*
    , col1 = PARSENAME(c,4)
    , col2 = PARSENAME(c,3)
    , col3 = PARSENAME(c,2)
    , col4 = PARSENAME(c,1)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,'/','.'),'(','.'),')','.'))) AS t1(c);
-- SQL Server 2017 onwards
--CROSS APPLY (VALUES (TRANSLATE(tokens,'/()','...'))) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A/B(D)C | A | B | D | C |
| 2 | Miami/Orlando(Denver)Hollywood | Miami | Orlando | Denver | Hollywood |